How to change the BlurView color to black?
I want the navigation bar to be black instead of gray.

I tried adjusting the color using background color, but that changed next to nothing.
My code:
        <Tabs
            screenOptions={{
                tabBarShowLabel: false,
                tabBarActiveTintColor: '#fff',
                tabBarLabelStyle: {
                    fontWeight: '500',
                },
                headerShown: false,
                tabBarStyle: {
                    height: STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT,
                    position: 'absolute',
                    borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
                    borderTopRightRadius: 0,
                    borderTopWidth: 0.2,
                    borderTopColor: '#262626',
                    paddingTop: 0,
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                },
                tabBarBackground: () => (
                    <BlurView
                        intensity={50}
                        tint="dark"
                        style={{
                            ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
                            overflow: 'hidden',
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
                            borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
                            borderTopRightRadius: 0,
                        }}
                    />
                ),
            }}
        >


Addendum: To date I have not found a solution so that the navigation bar is not gray but has a black blur (as Figma also shows). Unfortunately, it is still the case that when the navigation bar is on a black background it is grayish, which doesn't suit my design.

     tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: '#gray',
      tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor: '#000000',
      tabBarStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#fffffff',
      },


Unfortunately this doesn't work :(
The goal is for the navigation bar to have the BlurView 50, but not to have this gray color but to be black.
